# Unknown error between babel commands and xy-pic

Tags: babel, incompatibility, xy-pic

I'm writing an article in Spanish but it seems that I have an incompatibility between `babel` commands and `xy-pic`. There is an older topic on the same issue but the solution there is not working for me ([Bad interaction between babel and xy pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133562/bad-interaction-between-babel-and-xypic)).

This is a short version of the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter,openright,final]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Tuki tuki

\textit{Palabras clave}: tuki, tuki, tuki.
\end{abstract}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english} % THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
\begin{abstract}
Tookey Tookey

\textit{Keywords}: tookey, tookey, tookey.
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}


\begin{section}{Introducción}

Blah

\end{section}

\begin{section}{Sección}

Blah

$$\xymatrix@=1cm{
A \ar@{<->}[r]^{\oplus} \ar@{<->}[dr] & E\ar@{->}[d]^{\rhd}\\
I \ar@{<-}[u]^{\rhd} \ar@{<->}[ru]^{\hspace{3pt}\otimes} & O\ar@{<->}[l]^{\ominus}
}$$

blah

\end{section}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it (MiKTeX, using pdfLaTeX) I get this error:

> ```
> ! Xy-pic error: illegal <arrow>: macro:->\es@use@shorthand < not valid. \xyerror@ ...#2}\fi \errmessage {Xy-pic error: #1}
>                                                  } l.54 }
>      $$
> ```

There is a topic on this site ([xypic produces error when I try to use any arrow style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/xypic-produces-error-when-i-try-to-use-any-arrow-style)) where this error is discussed, but the solution there is useless for me, as `babel` is already loaded before `xy`. (I tried changing them anyway but I still got the problem.)

If I remove the `\otherlanguage` environment, I got no problem with `xymatrix`.

It gets the same with `\selectlanguage{english}` (...) `\selectlanguage{spanish}`.

BUT! If I put the `\otherlanguage` environment inside the `\abstract` environment, it works as it should. The problem is that I need the header of the abstract be "abstract" and not "resumen", for it is the English one (the Spanish one is before, as usual).

I was looking inside `babel` and `xy-pic` documentation but I still can't figure it out why this is happening.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Off-topic: Please read [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: Don't use `\begin{section}` and `\end{section}`, but just `\section`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use option `es-noquoting` if you do not need `<<` and `>>` as replacement for `\begin{quoting}` and `\end{quoting}`. Note that you can still use the synonyms `` "` `` and `"'`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish
  ,es-noquoting% <- added
]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{abstract}
Tookey Tookey
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{Introducción}
Blah
\section{Sección}
Blah
\[\xymatrix@=1cm{
A \ar@{<->}[r]^{\oplus} \ar@{<->}[dr] & E\ar@{->}[d]^{\rhd}\\
I \ar@{<-}[u]^{\rhd} \ar@{<->}[ru]^{\hspace{3pt}\otimes} & O\ar@{<->}[l]^{\ominus}
}\]

"`blah"'
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `\deactivatequoting`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\deactivatequoting% <- added
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{abstract}
Tookey Tookey
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}

\section{Introducción}
Blah
\section{Sección}
Blah
\[\xymatrix@=1cm{
A \ar@{<->}[r]^{\oplus} \ar@{<->}[dr] & E\ar@{->}[d]^{\rhd}\\
I \ar@{<-}[u]^{\rhd} \ar@{<->}[ru]^{\hspace{3pt}\otimes} & O\ar@{<->}[l]^{\ominus}
}\]

"`blah"'
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Spanish `babel` makes a few characters active and usable as commands make the source code prettier (they are `'`, `"`, `~`, `<`, `>`). The last two of them conflict with `xy-pic`. You has to deactivate them prior of using `\xymatrix@`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter,openright,final]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Tuki tuki

\textit{Palabras clave}: tuki, tuki, tuki.
\end{abstract}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english} % THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
\begin{abstract}
Tookey Tookey

\textit{Keywords}: tookey, tookey, tookey.
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}


\begin{section}{Introducción}

Blah

\end{section}

\begin{section}{Sección}

Blah
\spanishdeactivate{<>}
\[\xymatrix@=1cm{
A \ar@{<->}[r]^{\oplus} \ar@{<->}[dr] & E\ar@{->}[d]^{\rhd}\\
I \ar@{<-}[u]^{\rhd} \ar@{<->}[ru]^{\hspace{3pt}\otimes} & O\ar@{<->}[l]^{\ominus}
}\]

blah

\end{section}

\end{document}
```

I've also added `\usepackage{amssymb}` for the `\rhd` command.

Comment: Both this solution and the precedent were useful. Thanks!